# Composer install command run on production admin server accidentally & terminate in the middle before it's done pls let me know consequences/effects

Tags: magento2, adobe-commerce

I have one query for you please let me know if possible. Thanks

I run composer install command on production admin server through CLI accidentally and terminate in the middle when i realized it's a production server please let me know consequences/effects.

Magento 2 ( Adobe Commerce) Version: 2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Remove the vendor folder

```
rm -rf vendor
```

And then run composer again:

```
composer install
```

In this way, you will certify all vendors files are there.

Comment: I want to know that... when composer install is terminate in the middle before finishing..... so it will rollback or not by default.....as i mentioned i accidentally executed the command on admin production server and immediately terminate that..... after that i cross checked whole admin and front-end everything seems working fine as of now.. so just wanted technical views on the same....